# Creating a client within the application_controller.rb to avoid duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been learning a lot of rails through the Youtube_IT gem and as of now I have to insert

```
@client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "AI39 .. bGqx")
```

into every controller's def index manually so that it can appear in index.html.erb . I noticed that Rails have an application_controller.rb and thought it might be similar to the layout's application file where any code that goes in there becomes a universal thing.

I've tried creating an index method in the application_controller and inserting the dev key in there but no luck. What are some ways I can set it once for all controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :set_youtube_client, only: [:index]

private
def set_youtube_client
  @client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => 'AI39 ... bGqx')
end
```

**Or** you could add the following to your `aplication_controller.rb`:

```
def youtube_client
  @youtube_client ||= YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => 'AI39 ... bGqx')
end
helper_method :youtube_client
```

And then just use `youtube_client` in your views instead of `@client`

Comment: Extremely helpful and solved my problem! Thanks!!! Now I learned how to use before_action haha